# SSH no password problem

Tags: server, ssh, password

I start to do SSH session without password. Now I can connect to my server like this:

```
bash-3.2$ ./dev2
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/roger/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.11 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Wed Aug 23 08:25:06 2017 from 176.59.142.224
```

Now I edit sshd_config and add to the end this:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Restart server but ssh still ask me for pass phrase.

What should I do?

Comment: You need to enter the passphrase for the rsa key. What is unclear?

Comment: Not your server asks for a password, but your key. I see that if you of course use the same password for your key as for your server... That it could become confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 
you have pass of `pass phrase` when you create, so if you connect without `pass phrase` when SSH, you should create new key with command as:

```
**[test@test test]$ ssh-keygen**
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/test/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/home/test/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
ac:5e:9a:72:c6:cd:82:9c:cd:1f:bc:4d:de:f9:50:d9 tanto@hlink_backup_086
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|       .       o |
|        S     o E|
|       o     .   |
|   . *.o+ . .    |
|    =.B+o* . o   |
|     ++oo o o..  |
+-----------------+
```

On step `Enter passphrase,` you should enter empty. After create, you can add key `id_rsa.pub` to folder `.ssh/authorized_keys` of remote server, and check permission and change file authorized_keys with chmod 600:

```
[root@test test]# chmod -R 600 /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
[root@test test]# ls -l /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 test test 1212 Jul 12 14:17 /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys
```